# overlay widget on QTextEdit

Tags: qt, pyqt4

I tried:

```
widget = QWidget(text_edit)
```

but it doesn't give what I want. What's the correct way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: What does it give and what do you want?

Comment: @ArnoldSpence I just can't see the widget. Eventually, I would like a widget of the same width as its containing QTextEdit

Answer (score 0):

A parented instance of QWidget doesn't have anything for you to see (it's transparent), so try something like this:

```
..
QWidget *widget = new QWidget(text_edit); // assuming text_edit is a pointer
widget->setGeometry(0,0,text_edit->width(),20);
widget->setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: blue; }");
....
```